# what does the phrase "don't pimp me" mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context, slang

I watched the pilot episode of The Office (Season 1).

There, Michael says,

> "Oh, hey do you like the Jamie Kennedy Experiment? Yeah Punk'd, and all that kind of stuff? You are going to be my accomplice, just go on with that ok? All right Just follow my lead, ***don't pimp me*** all right? Come in! "

[Source](https://genius.com/The-office-us-pilot-script-annotated)

What does the phrase *"don't pimp me"* mean?

Answer (score 7):

"Pimping" is when someone ditches you or doesn't follow through with plans. [(source)](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Pimped)

So, **don't pimp me** would mean the same thing as **don't flake on me** or **don't ditch me**.

Notice that in this case, this phrase is a part of his instructions and is not used as a means of pressuring the other person to do it. After following Michael, the person whom he is instructing should not ditch him by leaving the scene.

In this case, it's very casual slang. But another meaning for "pimp" is someone who arranges clients for prostitutes, so be careful using the word, because the verb "pimping" could also be taken as "acting as a pimp" in a different context.

Comment: You could note the register of this use, it's very casual. And warn the OP of other meanings of the verb "pimp" (to earn money from prostitutes).